# 3d polyline offset along normal directions

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, numerical-methods

Suppose a 3d polyline (i.e. polygonal chain of 3d point segments) is given with normals specified for each points.

Are there any algorithms to compute an offset polyline whose points lie at specified distance from the source polyline along the normals so there is no self intersections?

Comment: Are you looking for a close surface in which cas only the normal length would be used, or only an open surface connecting 2 polylines?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am looking for a 3d polyline that lie at specified distance along the normal directions. It should be something similar to 2d polygon offset ( https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer_7_with_strategies.html ) but it 3d. It could be viewed as a search for a closed surface whose boundaries are the specified curve and the offset one.

Comment: Unless your curve is actually planar, chances that the curve self-intersects are virtually zero and you shouldn't worry. Just link the tips of the normals, with suitable scaling.

Comment: After reading previous comments, I see that you are not after a curve but after a surface, which is a very different (and difficult) problem. But what do you mean by "normals specified" then, what use are they ?

Comment: Thank for your reply. I think my curve can have some planar parts, so local/global self-intersections are possible. You are right, originally I was looking for a curve, but now I think I need a surface (mesh). In my case the curve is drawn on top of some mesh so the normals could be thought as the normals of the surface. I guess in this case the "offset curve" could be obtained from "offset mesh" (i.e. minkowski sum of the mesh with a ball).  But not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @deephace: sorry, your description with offset/curve/surface/mesh/normals is now very confuse. Can you show a figure ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://imgur.com/a/RnTN52q Here the red lines depict the normals. The pictures were taken from H.Shin "Directional Offset of a 3D Curve" article.

Comment: You can't avoid self-intersections if the normals and offset length mandate it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see the results of NX offset command. You maybe find the answer.